# POSTing variables to API (idibu) with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, post

I'm relatively new to AJAX and API calls and I'm working on a POST API call to a company called idibu that handles job postings. It requires POST variables (not GET variables) so I'm using a AJAX with a type of 'POST.' The POST data I'm using is from the idibu documentation as a working example for an API call (it's encoded in iso-8859-1, which is required, and can be read about here: http://www.idibuworld.com/docs/xml-api-v3-examples). There is a 'hash key' or API key that we've been provided but I took out of the code here (just letting you know that I've entered it correctly in my code). Here's my code:

```
<script>
$('.api_test').click(function(){

    var myData =
    'xml_text=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cidibu%3E%0D%0A%3Cmethod%3Eadd%3C%2Fmethod%3E%0D%0A%3Cconfig%3E%0D%0A%3Cshow_durations%3Eno%3C%2Fshow_durations%3E%0D%0A%3Ccompletionurl%3Eemail%3C%2Fcompletionurl%3E%0D%0A%3Cadvertcompletionemail%3Ebob%40bob.com%3C%2Fadvertcompletionemail%3E%0D%0A%3Clockboards%3Eyes%3C%2Flockboards%3E%0D%0A%3Credirecturl%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com+%3C%2Fredirecturl%3E%0D%0A%3Cvalidate_level%3Ewarning%3C%2Fvalidate_level%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fconfig%3E%0D%0A%3Cjob%3E%0D%0A%3Ctitle%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BXML+v+3+test%2C+please+ignore+Special+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%80%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%3Creference%3EABC123456789%3C%2Freference%3E%0D%0A%3Cdescription%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%3Cb%3ESpecial+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+here+euro+%80+%0D%0ABasic+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0ASpecial+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0A%0D%0A+%0D%0A+Special+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0ABasic+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0A%0D%0A+%96+%96+%92+%27+%95+++++++%2C+%09%2C+%95+%B7+%93+%94+%D8+%85+%A8+%A6+%27+%3A+%27+%83+%E1+%91+%BA+%A1+%A7+%E9+%D7+%87+%27+%3A+%27+%27+%C7+%BD+%84+h+%AE+%97+%AC+%83+%E1+%99%3C%2Fb%3E%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%0D%0A%3Csender%3E%0D%0A%3Cname%3ESteve%3C%2Fname%3E%0D%0A%3Clastname%3ERogers%3C%2Flastname%3E%0D%0A%3Cemail%3Etest%40mail.net%3C%2Femail%3E%0D%0A%3Ccompany%3EOne+World+Market%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%3Cphone%3E44+%280%29+111-1111111%3C%2Fphone%3E%0D%0A%3Cwww%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fuk.idibu.com+%3C%2Fwww%3E%0D%0A%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0D%0A%3Cpostcode%3E020+1111+1111%3C%2Fpostcode%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsender%3E%0D%0A%3Ccategory+id%3D%2221%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Clocation+id%3D%228%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Csublocation+id%3D%22668%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cjobtype+id%3D%222%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cjob_time%3E2%3C%2Fjob_time%3E%0D%0A%3Cstartdate%3E2011-11-26%3C%2Fstartdate%3E%0D%0A%3Cduration%3EFull+time%3C%2Fduration%3E%0D%0A%3Csalarymin%3E20000%3C%2Fsalarymin%3E%0D%0A%3Csalarymax%3E25000%3C%2Fsalarymax%3E%0D%0A%3Csalaryper+value%3D%22annum%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3CsalaryOverride%3ESalary+override+test+test%3C%2FsalaryOverride%3E%0D%0A%3Ccurrency%3EGBP%3C%2Fcurrency%3E%0D%0A%3Cpublish%3E2011-11-26%3C%2Fpublish%3E%0D%0A%3Cposts%3E%0D%0A%3Cboard+id%3D%22517%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cextrafield+name%3D%22idibudts_cat%22%3E3%3C%2Fextrafield%3E%0D%0A%3Cduration+days%3D%227%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fboard%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fposts%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fjob%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fidibu%3E';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: 'http://ws.idibu.com/clients/api/REMOTE/V3/[INSERT HASH KEY]', //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:'xml', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        async:false,
        data:myData, //post variables
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success:function(response){

            $("#preForXMLResponse").html('<pre>'+response+'</pre>');

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('didn\'t work'); //throw any errors
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Now, I'm not sure if the problem has anything to do with the actual 'data' being passed because it's giving me a the error on the AJAX call (it alerts out 'didn't work') meaning it never posted to anywhere.

Like I said, I'm new to this and have been reading up on how to send POST calls (and I have sent successful AJAX calls in the past on other projects). There's more documentation on idibu here (http://www.idibuworld.com/docs/submitting-and-responses), though I'm not sure if it's just a syntax error on my end. There's not great support yet for their API so I'm just trying to sort through it as best I can.

Thanks for help!

### EDIT

I get these errors on the console when I try to submit (again, I'm editing the code for privacy purposes but it's displaying my URL and HASH KEY in the actual errors):

```
Failed to load resource: Origin http://[MY_SITE] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. http://ws.idibu.com/clients/api/REMOTE/V3/[INSERT HASH KEY]

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ws.idibu.com/clients/api/REMOTE/V3/[INSERT HASH KEY]. Origin http://[MY_SITE] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

In this question ([Origin 'url' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216059/origin-url-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)), they mentioned that you can't make AJAX calls to sites outside of your server. Am I approaching this POST method incorrectly? This is on a PHP page so would you all suggest cURL (I'm not well-versed in it which is why I attempted jQuery AJAX)?

Comment: You should check the error on your browser's network tab (that must be on javascript console).

Comment: @ocanal, thanks for that. I've updated my question with those errors.

Comment: I did find this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin that may have a clue in it...

Comment: Those links that you've posted requires authentication.  Have you tried to load that url using GET request?  Just for debugging purpose I would try it in a browser with your hash key.  The reason I say this is because I want to assume people accepting `POST` would at least do it over `https`.

Comment: @vinodadhikary The GET request is not supported with the API. In their documentation, they say that it has to be POST. I suppose that's just the way it's set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer after your edit that contains the ERROR information,

Yes, it's impossible to make a request via ajax from another domain that is not allowed by the requested domain on client side.

There are some methods to achieve this problem,

[JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)

I can't access the idibu's API, so I have no idea whether that supports JSONP. You should check the docs and find if it does.

[CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)

You can't use this one, because in this method the idibu API must allow your domain on their side. I wouldn't pass this off without mention.

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

As you mentioned in your edit, If you are able to make this request via cURL, just do it. There are no restrictions like Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Ok great, thank you for the details. This gives me a great place to start!